# UITableView cell contents load fine on iOS 9 but not on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have been experiencing this event where `UITableView` cell contents are loaded fine on iOS 9, but not on iOS 8. I have verified this both on the simulator and on the device.

I have tried loading the data on `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and even in `viewDidAppear` but still the same. I have tried a `dispatch_async` to reload the the `tableView` but still the same.

Check the images below to see the problem I am experiencing.

[image: iOS 9]
[image: iOS 8]

However, when I tap the position for the stars, the `UIView` for the stars suddenly appears.

[image: iOS8 2]

Here is my code for the `UITableView` controller.

```
@interface EvalTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *allItems;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *items;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ratings;

@end

@implementation EvalTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    _allItems = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AssessmentItems" ofType:@"plist"]];    
    _items = nil;
    _items = [_allItems objectForKey:_currentEval];

    [self loadRatings];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"itemCellId";
    ItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.item.text = _items[indexPath.row];
    cell.ratingView.value = ((NSNumber *)_ratings[indexPath.row]).floatValue;
    [cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.ratingView];
    [cell.ratingView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateRating:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell layoutSubviews];
    return cell;
}

- (void)updateRating:(HCSStarRatingView *)ratingView {
    long indexOfRatingView = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(ItemTableViewCell *)[[ratingView superview] superview]].row;
    [_ratings replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfRatingView withObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:ratingView.value]];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfRatingView inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

- (void)loadRatings {
    _ratings = nil;
    _ratings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.count; i++) {
        [_ratings addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:1.0]];
    }
}
}
```

I have not added anything on the `ItemTableViewCell` code. Here it is:

```
@implementation ItemTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

I am new on iOS app development, I hope you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: which Class are you using for the star rating?

Comment: check my question again, I have the added the code.

Comment: @abhi1992 I am using this star rating control I have found [link](https://github.com/hsousa/HCSStarRatingView)

Comment: Calling `[cell layoutSubviews];` directly is discouraged. BTW, Could you post `ItemTableViewCell` codes? :)

Comment: @user3480295 thanks for the info, I will keep that in mind. :) I have edited my post to include the `ItemTableViewCell` codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all our past efforts to solve my problem was more focused on loading the cells, and not on the `UITableViewCell` itself.

I have found out that the problem lies on my constraints for my label and for the star rating. I just added a `height` constraint to my star rating and it becomes visible when the tableView appears. I also needed to put `[self.tableView reloadData];` on my `viewDidAppear` method.

However, the `UITableViewCell` displays in its fixed height initially, then adjusts it's height after the view is presented to the user which might not be appealing for the user. And the tableView scrolls when I tap the star rating.

But anyways, this gave me hope in solving my problem.

I just find it odd. Because, if it's a constraint or layout error, why does it work fine on iOS 9 and not on iOS 8?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in the awakefromnib method in the tableViewCell.m file(after importing **HCSStarRatingView** ).Also try the debugging mode in simulator to see if the view is there before the first touch.

```
HCSStarRatingView *starRatingView = [[HCSStarRatingView alloc] initWithFrame:initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.ratingView.frame.size.width,  self.ratingView.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: I have tried adding the initWithFrame, but still no good. How do I use the debugging mode? Thanks

Comment: run the app in simulator and then you can see a view Hierarchy mode button at the bottom( https://sesamenotes.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/screen-shot-2015-07-22-at-8-03-32-am.png ).Go through the above link.

Comment: I just tried it, but it seems that the star rating is not rendered at all. The simulator becomes unresponsive after using the hierarchy mode.

Comment: On first run on hierarchy mode, the frame for the star rating is not visible. I run again and tapped on the view to display it. I then used the hierarchy mode and I can see the star rating there, with all other star rating frames, but no drawing.

Comment: The simulator becomes unresponsive after using the hierarchy mode.that is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is problem with bring subview to front may be.

please try this in cell for row at index path method .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"itemCellId";
ItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.item.text = _items[indexPath.row];
cell.ratingView.value = ((NSNumber *)_ratings[indexPath.row]).floatValue;
//[cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.ratingView];
[cell.ratingView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateRating:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell layoutSubviews];
return cell;
}
```

And if it is still not working than in view did load add this code and test again.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

_allItems = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AssessmentItems" ofType:@"plist"]];    

_items = nil;
_items = [_allItems objectForKey:_currentEval];

[self.tableView reloadData];
[self loadRatings]; 

}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but still no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Please check your screen in 3d view from Xcode . Is there any view that hides your rating view ? and also try to reload data after load ratings as Abhishek Gupta said.

Comment: Is it the same as the hierarchy mode? I have used the hierarchy mode but it seems that the subview is not rendered at all.

Comment: Are you using different start image in rating view to show empty stars ?

Comment: I am not using any images to render the star ratings. The drawings are all coded based from what I understand in the control.

Comment: https://github.com/hsousa/HCSStarRatingView/issues/21 is this related to your issue ? please check it once.

Comment: I will look into this. Thanks for effort and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After calling  `[self loadRatings];` , you need to reload your table data try it.

Comment: Please check with :  ItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; and replace with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: